# Comparison of multiple means using summarized data

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have means, variances, and sample sizes from three geographical sites but not their raw data such that:

```
     site1 site2 site3
N      120  150   160
mean   27.1 32.6  42.3
sd     5.5  7.1   6.8
```

I know we can do a pairwise z/t test just using these information. I'm wondering whether I can conduct a F test or Anova for a hypothesis $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3$ vs $H_1:$ as least one pair of means are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Please see [this paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1992.10475872#.VEAiMBZn06U) by Larson for reference.

Stata has a user-contributed `aovsum` command that allows recreating ANOVA analysis using just summary data. SAS has a [macro](http://support.sas.com/kb/25/020.html) and R has an 
`ind.oneway.second` function in the [rpsychi](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpsychi/rpsychi.pdf) package for similar purpose.

If you don't know any of these software packages, online calculator like [this](http://statpages.org/anova1sm.html) is also available.

Comment: Thanks, Penguin_Knight. Do you know any R package for that purpose?

Comment: @DavidZ See `ind.oneway.second` in the [rpsychi](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpsychi/rpsychi.pdf) package.